# Hide Firebase App Check debugging secret key for development in React

Tags: reactjs, firebase, recaptcha-v3, firebase-app-check

When using Firebase App check, one needs to use a special secret key when in development, as reCAPTCHA only works on the app's actual domain (see [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/web/debug-provider#web-version-9)). Using create-react-app I'm not sure about where to hide this key so that it is completely invisible in production but available to the code in development. Also, I want this to be as automatic as can be.

Comment: The secret key goes on the Google side, project settings, reCAPTCHA secret key. Your app carries the public key, no need to hide it.

Answer (score 1):

As I'm reading the question I'm assuming that you have already done the setup of the project.

- What you need to do now is to get your key from the dev tools console its described how in the Firebase docs [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/web/debug-provider?hl=en&authuser=0).
  After that you go to:
- Firebase console -> App Check -> Apps -> Three dots -> Manage debug tokens -> Add debug token
- After adding it I've added it to my code but with check if the env is prod or dev
- Instead of hardcoding it directly you can add it to your .env file

  ```
    if (!process.env.NODE_ENV || process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
      window.FIREBASE_APPCHECK_DEBUG_TOKEN = 'your_debug_token';
    }
  ```

- For more details of the whole setup you can check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72879527/implementing-firebase-appcheck-for-react-web/74322825#74322825)